# Enforce screen break automatically every hour

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mate

I am using Ubunte Mate 16.04. I would like to know if it is possible to lock the screen every hour automatically? I does not matter if the computer is idle or not. After working for an hour a screen break for at least 5 minutes should be enforced by locking the screen. After 5 minutes have elapsed the work may be continued.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Your question is about Ubuntu. You would probably get better expertise, and therefore better answers on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com). Please flag your question to be migrated, or delete your question and re-ask it over there. Please do not cross-post (i.e. ask your question on Ask Ubuntu before you delete here or your question is migrated) You may ask your question there once you have deleted your question here.

Comment: @ubashu My question is generally about Linux. I happen to use Ubuntu currently but this might very well change in the future. If every question that involved Ubuntu were to be migrated then I really do not see any point in having the Ubuntu-tag here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_repetitive_strain_injury_software) on rsi software gives some links to Linux tools. [pokoy](https://github.com/ttygde/pokoy) seems to fit your requirements, with a [configuration file](https://github.com/ttygde/pokoy/blob/master/pokoy.1.txt) of options like

```
enable_skip <true/false>:
 If set to true, user can press 's' to skip break.
enable_postpone <true/false>:
 If set to true, user can press 'p' to postpone break.
break <time_between_breaks> <break_duration> <postpone_time>:
```

You need to compile it, so may need to install `libxcb-devel`.

Comment: I use [Workrave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workrave), available in the Ubuntu's repository.

Answer (score 1):

with MATE as desktop environment you can easily achieve this with an onboard-tool:

open the *Control Center* and search for *Keyboard*; in the following window go to the *Typing Break*-tab and check the first checkbox... the settings should be self-explaining.

[image: Keyboard Preferences]